# ReyclerView. Police Data Json - No adapter attached, skipping layout

Tags: android, json, layout, android-recyclerview

Good afternoon guys, I am trying to fetch some data from the police data website.

Unfortunately, the application doesn't show any data saying "**E/`RecyclerView`: No adapter attached; skipping layout**".

I have attached the `LatestCrimesActivity`, adapter and the `ListItem` class.

Thank you for your help.

This is `LatestCrimesActivity`:

```
package com.example.cosmin.crimerate.Latest_crimes_api;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.cosmin.crimerate.R;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LatestCrimesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String URL_DATA = "https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?poly=52.268,0.543:52.794,0.238:52.130,0.478&date=2017-01";

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    private List<ListItem> listItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_latest_crimes);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewlatest);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        listItems=new ArrayList<>();

        loadRecyclerViewData();


        }

    private void loadRecyclerViewData() {

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading data...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                URL_DATA,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("");

                            for (int i=0; i<array.length();i++){
                                JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                ListItem item = new ListItem(
                                        o.getString("category"),
                                        o.getString("location_type"),
                                        o.getString("street"),
                                        o.getString("status")
                                );
                                listItems.add(item);

                            }
                            adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems, getApplicationContext());
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


}
```

Adapter:

```
package com.example.cosmin.crimerate.Latest_crimes_api;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.cosmin.crimerate.R;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Cosmin on 25/11/2017.
 */

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {



    private List<ListItem> listItems;

    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(List<ListItem> listItems, LatestCrimesActivity latestCrimesActivity) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);

        holder.textViewCat.setText(listItem.getCategory());
        holder.textViewLoc.setText(listItem.getLocation());
        holder.textViewStreet.setText(listItem.getStreet());
        holder.textViewStatus.setText(listItem.getStatus());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return listItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView textViewCat;
        public TextView textViewLoc;
        public TextView textViewStreet;
        public TextView textViewStatus;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            textViewCat = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCat);
            textViewLoc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewLoc);
            textViewStreet = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewStreet);
            textViewStatus = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewStatus);

        }
    }
}
```

This is `ListItem` class:

```
package com.example.cosmin.crimerate.Latest_crimes_api;

/**
 * Created by Cosmin on 25/11/2017.
 */

public class ListItem {

    private String category;
    private String location;
    private String street;
    private String status;

    public ListItem (String category, String location, String street, String status){
        this.category=category;
        this.location=location;
        this.street=street;
        this.status=status;
    }
    public String getCategory (){
        return category;
    }
    public String getLocation (){
        return location;
    }
    public String getStreet (){
        return street;
    }
    public String getStatus (){
        return status;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to change some lines. First set adapter before your api call.

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewlatest);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    listItems=new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new MyAdapter(listItems, getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then when you received the answer, fill listItems, then call `notifyDataSetChange()` method of your adapter object.

Comment: Yes, it worked partially. Following your steps, the error is gone, unfortunately, the data is still not coming up. :(

Comment: did you call the method I said?

Comment: Yes, of course, unfortunately I believe the json is not valid :( . if you can please have a look for me

Comment: Actually, I've never worked with Volly. I use Retrofit for these kinds of stuff and it's really easy to work with. It converts the response to the object itself, using Gson. BTW, you created your object wrong. Go http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and paste your json. It converts it to a java class which works with Gson